# How to get biggest size row from excel sheet using Apache POI or any other in JAVA?

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I have a excel file random cells in each row like this

[image]

i am using Apache POI for get sheets, rows and cells, i want to find row which contain most number of cell then i need cell count of that row

ie according to my example file expecting answer is

---

**3rd row contains 7 cells**

---

my code

---

```
package volumata.web.service;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser;
import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
import org.apache.tika.parser.Parser;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelReader {
    public static final String SAMPL_XLSX_FILE_PATH = "/home/volumata/Desktop       /sample.xlsx";

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException, TikaException, Exception {
        // READ xslx file
        File file = new File(SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH);
        if (file.exists()) {
            double bytes = file.length();
            System.out.println("bytes : " + bytes);
        } else {
            System.out.println("File does not exists!");
        }
        // parameters of parse() method
        Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
        BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(file);
        ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
        // Parsing the given file
        parser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata, context);
        // list of meta data elements elements
        System.out.println(" metadata elements and values of the given file :");
        String[] metadataNamesb4 = metadata.names();
        for (String name : metadataNamesb4) {
            System.out.println(name + ": " + metadata.get(name) + "   Size:" + metadata.hashCode());
            metadata.size();
        }
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        System.out.println("Workbook name:" + file.getName());
        workbook.getNumberOfFonts();
        System.out.println("Workbook name:" + file.getName());
        System.out.println("Sheet count:" + workbook.getNumberOfSheets());
        Iterator itesheet = workbook.sheetIterator();
        int j = 1;
        XSSFSheet sheet1 = (XSSFSheet) itesheet.next();
        Iterator rowIter = sheet1.rowIterator();
        Row r = (Row) rowIter.next();
        short lastCellNum = r.getLastCellNum();
        int[] dataCount = new int[lastCellNum];
        System.out.println("sheet lastCellNum:" + lastCellNum);
        System.out.println("sheet dataCount:" + dataCount.length);
        while (itesheet.hasNext()) {
            XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) itesheet.next();
            sheet.getColumnOutlineLevel(0);
            System.out.println("sheet getColumnOutlineLevel:" + sheet.getColumnOutlineLevel(1));
            Iterator ite = sheet.rowIterator();
            System.out.println();
            int i = 1;
            while (ite.hasNext()) {
                Row row = (Row) ite.next();
                System.out.println(row.getOutlineLevel());
                System.out.println(i + "-Cell count:" + row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells());
                Iterator<Cell> cite = row.cellIterator();
                while (cite.hasNext()) {
                    Cell c = cite.next();
                    System.out.print(c.toString() + "  ");
                }
                i++; // System.out.println();
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question/problem?

Comment: You can use a `int maxValue` and a `int currentValue`. Then you juste have to check for each row if the cell contains something or not. Then increment `currentValue`, and at the end of the row, compare it to `maxValue` and save it if bigger than that. What is difficult in this ?

Comment: @Melebius Normally I would agree with you, but OP already has the proper answer (`row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells()`) in his code

Comment: Thank you for quick response, i can do this but imagine if the file is bigger contains billions of records,

Comment: @xtremebaumer,  i want to find largest row (which contains most cell count) without loop all rows

Comment: It is not possible without looping. The only other way would be a `stream`, but I doubt you would gain anything from it. If you fear an exception because of too many records, then you should switch to `SXSSFWorkbook`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer do you know how to find total column in the sheet?

Comment: There seems to be no way without iterationg

Comment: Thank you so much Mr@XtremeBaumer for spent time with my question